# Get data of picked point from Bokeh chart

Tags: python, bokeh

I have a bokeh-application (0.11.1) with a figure containing line plots. I know that it is possible to get data of a point using the hover or tap tool client side using CustomJS callbacks. Is it however possible to know server-side which datapoint the user has selected? Maybe via creating a CustomJS sending the data back to the server?

Comment: Using JS would be a JS problem not Bokeh's one. Why not using a bokeh server ?